# HTML5 history popstate with ajax, direct link not work

Tags: html, jquery, html5-history

This Demo I want to click forward to `content`(index.php?id=id) click back to `subject`(index.php).

Q1. (index.php?id=id) direct link `content` page not available, it will show (index.php) `subject` , why?

Q2. Click back after the second times (forward > back > forward > back) then url will stop change, why? (Safari 5)
update: Use `window.onpopstate` url works fine. Not get this error.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:location.pathname,
        success: function(data){
            $('.container').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo

```
$('.subject').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?id=' + $(this).attr('rel'),
            success: function(data){
                $('.container').html(data);
            }
    });
    var pageurl;
    pageurl = 'index.php?id=' + $(this).attr('rel');
    if(pageurl != window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path: pageurl}, "", pageurl);
    }
    return false;
});
```

index.php

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
        if($_GET['id']){
           ...
            print"<div class="content"></div>";
        }
        else{
           ...
           print"<div class="subject" rel="id"></div>"
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You save the URL via `history.pushState()`, but you never use it in your `popstate` handler. In that handler you could use `event.state.path` instead of `location.pathname`, which you use currently for the `url` param of your XHR call. (You would need to change `, function() {` to `, function(event) {` as well.)

Answer (score 1):

The popstate event handler will receive an *event* object which contains the *state* you passed in to pushState. It's accessible via `event.state` Here's the [event interface definition](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#popstateevent). Here's some demo code to illustrate the concept.

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
if( event.state !== null )    
    alert('Browser back button was clicked, state returned ' + JSON.stringify( event.state ) ); 
};
```

Comment: The alert states 'back button', but it could just as well have been the forward button.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to fetch the page content(i.e. subject for your scenario) using ajax and show it in your page container. Consider if you are in 'index.php' and clicks on a subject.. so your url changes to 'index.php?id=7'. Now you are clicking back.. here in 'popstate' event, 'location.pathname' gives 'http://host/index.php'. Thats it, fetch the data from 'location.pathname' using ajax and show it.

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:location.pathname,
        success: function(data){
            $('.content').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I want to click back (to index.php) only subject can be seen. is it possible?  I'm following this, just change url (to index.php) content still be seen.

Comment: Try $(window).bind('popstate', function(){return false;} Not sure, whether it will work.

Comment: Have a <div id='container'>...</div> and have this as container for the page. In ajax set the data for $('#container).html(data);

Comment: Thank for reply, it is what i'm looking for, click forward only show content,back only show subject. But update the code in question, when I click the second times back (forward>back>forwarad) >back the url not change, still with `?=id`.

Comment: and the article `index.php?=id` link not available